# No method to get JSON array from JSON object

Tags: android, json

I am using simple_Json, I saw examples on net to convert JSON response to JSON object arrays.

here is how I am trying to get array, but not sure why I am not getting method to get jason array.

```
JSONObject jsonObject =(JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(response.toString());           

JSONObject s = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("GetMyRootFoldersForTreeResult");
JSONArray array = /** Not sure how to get array */
```

[image]

and here is JSON response:

```
{"GetMyRootFoldersForTreeResult":[{"Folder":{"isDirty":false,"isNew":false,"AllTagsData":null,"Archived":false,"ArchivedBy":null,"ArchivedDate":"\/Date(-6847824600000+0530)\/","CreatedBy":"SYSTEM","CreatedOnDate":"\/Date(1321523609427+0530)\/","EntityDescription":null,"EntityName":"System","ModifiedBy":"SYSTEM","ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1321523609427+0530)\/","State":null,"AdministratorViewOnly":false,"EntityFolderID":null,"Hidden":false,"HistoryFolderID":null,"CanBeRoot":true,"DefaultPageName":null,"FolderBehaviorType":"DecisionsFramework.ServiceLayer.Utilities.SystemFolder","FolderID":"SYSTEM FOLDER","FolderTypeName":"Folder","FullPath":"System","HasSubFolders":true,"IsSecurityFolder":true,"IsSystemFolder":true,"NestingLevel":1,"SecurityFolderId":"SYSTEM FOLDER","ShowInTree":true,"SubMenuBehavior":0,"SubMenuGroupName":null},"HasSubFolders":true},{"Folder":{"isDirty":false,"isNew":false,"AllTagsData":null,"Archived":false,"ArchivedBy":null,"ArchivedDate":"\/Date(-6847824600000+0530)\/","CreatedBy":"SYSTEM","CreatedOnDate":"\/Date(1321523675797+0530)\/","EntityDescription":null,"EntityName":"CMDB","ModifiedBy":"SYSTEM","ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1321523675797+0530)\/","State":null,"AdministratorViewOnly":false,"EntityFolderID":null,"Hidden":false,"HistoryFolderID":null,"CanBeRoot":true,"DefaultPageName":null,"FolderBehaviorType":"Decisions.TaskTracking.Service.Asset.AssetFolderBehavior","FolderID":"Asset_BASE_FOLDER_ID","FolderTypeName":"Asset Folder","FullPath":"CMDB","HasSubFolders":false,"IsSecurityFolder":true,"IsSystemFolder":false,"NestingLevel":1,"SecurityFolderId":"Asset_BASE_FOLDER_ID","ShowInTree":true,"SubMenuBehavior":0,"SubMenuGroupName":null},"HasSubFolders":false},{"
```

and I want to fetch Folder array.

Comment: `JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetMyRootFoldersForTreeResult");` ... but  maybe i'm wrong ... you didn't provide whole json response so it's hard to answer

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/8019007/964741

Comment: The 'Folder' object is not an array. It is inside the array GetMyRootFoldersForTreeResult. You can obtain the JSONArray, and after you must give every elements of this array with the getString method

Comment: The library you are using is probably json-simple, and not simple_jason

Comment: Try using this as android has in-built json library.`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());           
         JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetMyRootFoldersForTreeResult");
`.Try to parse the string outside this.

Comment: @Shashank I am developing android apps only

Comment: Don't know why but people here are fond of doing down vote than better answering question..Well now I am getting GetJSONArray method..I changed the referenced jar file.

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject jsonObject =(JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(response.toString());           
         JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetMyRootFoldersForTreeResult");
```

try this.

Comment: I know we can use jsonObject.GetJSONArray. But I am not getting any such GetJSONArray method inside jsonObject

Answer (score 2):

`simple-json` doesn't have those methods. Use `java-json.jar` instead.